# Конечно! Всё(,) как договаривались

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Я бы не стал ставить запятую, объясняя это тем, что вторую часть можно заменить *по договорённости.* Так правильно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Конечно! ВсЁ, как договАривались.***

Сравнить: *Делай как договАривались.*

Запятая в приведенном предложении ставится. Всё (так), как договаривались.

Это СПП с местоименно-определительным придаточным, нет оснований для того, чтобы не ставить там запятую.  Замена придаточного одним словом — это еще не повод, здесь нужен **интонационно-структурный анализ**.

Интонационно в предложении явно присутствует пауза, а также ударением выделено местоимение "все". А грамматика? Можно ли считать придаточное устойчивым оборотом?

Розенталь рассматривает эту тему, например: **Делай как нрАвится** (по-своему). Если оборот не обособляется, то ударение падает только на оборот, который обычно можно заменить обстоятельством.

Но: **Делай всё, как нравится.** Здесь запятая нужна.

Comment: Спасибо! Значит, не зря я поставил запятую, а думал, ошибся. Но всё-таки я не ставлю ударение на *всё!* Только на *догова́ривались.*

Comment: Тем можно не делать логического ударения, но тоническое ударение хотя бы перед  небольшой паузой присутствует естественным образом.